# Mean time to failure of a system problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The problem:
A system has 2 components: A and B. These components have independent lifetimes that are
exponentially distributed with parameters 2 and 3 respectively. (Recall an exponential
prob. density function with parameter $λ$ is $λe^{−λt}$. The system fails as soon as one component fails.

Part C asks the following:
(c) What is the mean time to failure for the system?

Hint: Define $Z = min(X, Y )$. Then the continuous distribution function of Z is 
$F_Z(z) = P(Z ≤ z) = P(X ≤ z, Y ≥ z) + P(X ≥ z, Y ≤ Z) = F_X(z)(1 − F_Y (z)) + F_Y (z)(1 − F_X(z))$

The answer is given as $1/5$, which I cannot seem to be able to get. Can someone explain why I am setting $Z=min(X,Y)$? Where do i go once I've done what the hint says?

Comment: Try to use latex to format your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If $X$ is the time to failure for component $A$ and $Y$ is the time to failure for component $B$, then $Z = \min(X,Y)$ is the time to failure for the whole system since the whole system fails as soon as one of its components fail. That's why we consider $Z = \min(X,Y)$.

Comment: Thank you! So does that mean I need to calculate the expected value of Z (ie. $E(Z)$)?

Comment: Actually, I think the hint is wrong since we have $Z < z$ iff either ($X < z$ and $Y$ arbitrary) or ($X > z$ and $Y < z$). We can ignore any of the equalities $X=z$,$Y=z$,$Z=z$ since we're dealing with continuous distributions. This translates to set notation $\{Z < z\} = \{X< z\} \cup \{X > z\ and\ Y < z\}$ where the union is obviously disjoint. This means that, when we take probabilities, we can add the probabilities on the r.h.s. and get $P(Z < z) = P(X < z) + P(X > z\ and Y < z) = P(X < z) + P(X > z)P(Y < z)$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: [continued] Translating this in turn to distribution functions, we get $F_Z(z) = F_X(z) + (1-F_X(z))F_Y(z) = F_X(z)+F_Y(z)-F_X(z)F_Y(z)$. Note that we get the same result if we exchange the roles of $X$ and $Y$ in my previous comment. That's somewhat reassuring. Anyway, my result for $F_Z(z)$ is different from that in the hint. What do you get?

Comment: Once you have $F_z$, you can use it to calculate $E(Z)$, for example via $$E(Z) = \int_0^\infty P(Z\geq t)dt = \int_0^\infty(1-F_Z(t))dt.$$

Comment: And yes, you have to calculate $E(Z)$. The expected value of $Z$ is the mean time to failure for the system.

Comment: The right answer! thank you so much for that very helpful explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $Z \ge z$ occurs if and only if $X \ge z$ and $Y \ge z.$ So $$P[Z \ge z]=P[X \ge z]P[Y \ge z]$$

$$P[Z \ge z]=e^{- \lambda_1z} e^{- \lambda_2 z}=e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)z}$$

Now it can be seen that $Z$ is itself an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2.$ So it has mean $$E[Z]={1 \over {\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}}= {1 \over 5}.$$